# How can I add pagination on shopify API products with rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, pagination, shopify

I'm using the rails gem [shopify API gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) to fetch shopify products. I'm fetching products like this:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { page: parmas[:page], 
                                          limit: 10, 
                                          title: params[:search]
                                        })
```

this API returns products searched by title with limit 10.
So How can I add pagination on my view or can I use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem for it?
Please help!, thanks! in advance.

Comment: You can use  [kaminari gem](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari). This gem can convert array into paginatable array

Comment: But I think it's not useful with shopify API because I can't fetch all products from shopify in one API call. I'll have to pass params page in shopify API call and it will return 10 products at a time. When I call shopify API I can track total count of products and can fetch products according to page. but I'm unable to manage those products on view.

Answer (score 1):

I think is late for your work. But this how to it:

Example

```
@orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => {:status => "any", :limit => 3, :order => "created_at DESC" })
@orders.each do |order|

  id = order.id
  name = order.name
end

while @orders.next_page?
  @orders = @orders.fetch_next_page
  @orders.each do |order|

    id = order.id
    name = order.name
  end
end
```

So you can create paginable array based on what you receive in each loop. The first call defines the limit for all subsequents call to fetch_next_page. In my case each page contain 3 element, you can go up to 250.

Another way is to navigate using shopify "next_page_info" parameter, so you only need to fetch the first query and include all filters, then just navigate back/fwd with page infos(previous_page_info or next_page_info).

```
Example 2
first_batch_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 50 })
  second_batch_products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 50, page_info: first_batch_products.next_page_info })

next_page_info = @orders.next_page_info
prev_page_info = @orders.previous_page_info
```

More info here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api#pagination

Regards.

Comment: .next_page is no longer an available method, they say the link is in the response headers now (https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-rest), but the shopify_app gem doesn't have any documentation how to get the response headers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Kaminari.paginate_array(*args)` with array(array of Shopify products) as first argument and with option as hash, where you have to set value to `total_count` key.

Full example:

```
@paginatable_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(@shopify_products, total_count:145).page(1).per(10)
```

use `1` as argument to `.page` method, because your array will contain only 10 objects(if limit is 10 and 10 objects in view)
In view just use helper method

```
<%= paginate @paginatable_array %>
```

I hope that it will help!